Fetch Request in Svelte onMount Hook Not Calling API Endpoint (bypassing hooks.server.ts)
I am developing a Svelte application and facing an issue where a fetch request in the onMount hook appears to not be executing or not be affected by the code written in my 'hooks.server.ts' file. I'm trying to authenticate a user by fetching user details from /api/user/ when the component mounts. I have my hooks.server.ts set up in such a way that a request to '/api//' should be manipulated in such a way that the right headers and cookies are added to the request and the request gets sent to an external back-end. However, it seems like the fetch request failing silently, as the evident network activity for this request in the browser's developer tools suggests that it is trying to directly access '/api/user/' instead of '{VITE_API_BASE_URL}/api/user'.
Note that for all my other requests, like '/api/login/' or '/api/register/' located at '/src/lib/api/POST/registration.ts', the web-hooks are applied correctly and I'm able to succesfully register or log in.
// hooks.server.ts
import { VITE_API_BASE_URL } from '$env/static/private';
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';


export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  const {request} = event;

  const getCookie = (name: string, cookies: string | null): string | null => {
    if (!cookies) {
      return null;
    }
    const cookieValue = cookies.split(';').find(c => c.trim().startsWith(`${name}=`));
    return cookieValue ? decodeURIComponent(cookieValue.split('=')[1]) : null;
  };
  
  if (event.url.pathname.startsWith('/api/')) {
    const requestHeaders = Object.fromEntries(request.headers);
    const isApiRequest = requestHeaders['x-requested-with'] === 'XMLHttpRequest';
    if (!isApiRequest) {
      return await resolve(event);
    }
    const cookies = request.headers.get('cookie');
    const csrfToken = getCookie('csrftoken', cookies);
    const headers: HeadersInit = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    if (csrfToken) {
      headers['X-CSRFToken'] = csrfToken;
    }
    
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${VITE_API_BASE_URL}${event.url.pathname}`, {
        method: request.method,
        headers: { 
          ...request.headers,
          ...headers
        },
        body: request.method !== 'GET' && request.method !== 'HEAD' ? await request.text() : undefined
      });

      return new Response(response.body, {
        status: response.status,
        statusText: response.statusText,
        headers: response.headers
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ status: 500, message: 'Internal client error' }), {
        status: 500,
        statusText: 'Internal client error',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      });
    }
  } 

  return await resolve(event);
}

// auth.svelte
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import { authenticated } from '../stores/auth';
  import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
  import { user } from '../stores/user';

  async function checkAuthentication() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/user/', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            credentials: 'include',
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const content = await response.json();
            authenticated.set(true);
            user.set({ firstName: content.first_name, lastName: content.last_name, email: content.email });
            return content;
        } else {
            authenticated.set(false);
            await goto('/login');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        authenticated.set(false);
        await goto('/login');
    }
}

onMount(async () => {
    await checkAuthentication();
});
</script>

I've tried changing the URL to the direct database URL. This works, but it now of course isn't adding the necessary headers and it is exposing the backend URL to the end-user.
For the record, the following code does correctly make use of the hooks:
// registration.ts
import type { ApiError, RegistrationData, LoginData } from '../../types';

export async function loginUser(loginData: LoginData): Promise<{ response?: Response, error?: ApiError}> {
  const headers: HeadersInit = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  };
  
  const response = await fetch('/api/login/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    return { response };
  } 

  const error = await response.json().then((data) => {
    return {
      status: response.status,
      message: data.error || 'An unexpected error occured',
      data: data,
    };
  });
  return { error };
}

export async function registerUser(registrationData: RegistrationData): Promise<{ response?: Response, error?: ApiError}> {
  const headers: HeadersInit = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  };
  
  const response = await fetch('/api/register/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(registrationData),
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    return { response };
  } 

  const error = await response.json().then((data) => {
    return {
      status: response.status,
      message: data.error || 'An unexpected error occured',
      data: data,
    };
  });
  return { error };
}

